# Carry value forward in dataframe with condition

Tags: r

I have a table that looks like this:

```
Price        Discount
$30            0
$39            0
$31            0
$20            1
$20            1
$20            1
$39            0
$28            0
```

I want to mutate a prevailing price column that will carry the price immediately before the discount period throughout the discount period, with the result like this:

```
Price        Discount      PrevailingPrice
$30            0              $30
$39            0              $39
$31            0              $31
$20            1              $31 
$20            1              $31
$20            1              $31
$29            0              $29 
$28            0              $28
```

In excel, I would just tell it to grab the previous value in the column, but you can't grab a value in a column that you're building through a mutate. I have been staring at this for hours. I am flummoxed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In base R you could do:

```
df$prevailingPrice = with(df, Price[(!Discount)*seq(Price)+ Discount*cumsum(!Discount)])

  Price Discount prevailingPrice
1   $30        0             $30
2   $39        0             $39
3   $31        0             $31
4   $20        1             $31
5   $20        1             $31
6   $20        1             $31
7   $39        0             $39
8   $28        0             $28
```

Comment: Can you break this down? I've been sitting here studying it. I think you've created an index that says prevailingPrice = Price[1,2,3,3,3,3,7,8]. (!Discount) * seq(Price) must = 1 for the first row. seq(Price) must equal 1, so (!Discount) must also equal 1. Does ! on a bool convert is to its opposite? So then Discount * cumsum(!Discount) is 1 * 3. This part doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Oooooh...cumsum(!Discount) adds to three by row 4. But it adds zeros after that! Brilliant!

Comment: @Parazen seq(Price) gives you 1,2,3,4,...8. !Discount gives you TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,.... multiplying the two we get 1,2,3,0,0,0,7,8. cumsum(!Discount) gives you 1,2,3,3,3,3,4,5. Multiplying with Discount we get 0,0,0,3,3,3,0,0. Now we add the 2, 1,3,3,0,0,0,7,8 +0,0,0,3,3,3,0,0=1,2,3,3,3,3,7,8.

Answer (score 2):

Use `ifelse` to add `NA`s to `PrevailingPrice` then use `tidyr::fill` to fill in the missing values.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- read_table2("
Price        Discount
30            0
39            0
31            0
20            1
20            1
20            1
39            0
28            0 
")
```

```
df %>%
  mutate(
    PrevailingPrice = ifelse(Discount == 1, NA, Price)
  ) %>%
  fill(PrevailingPrice)
#> # A tibble: 8 x 3
#>   Price Discount PrevailingPrice
#>   <dbl>    <dbl>           <dbl>
#> 1    30        0              30
#> 2    39        0              39
#> 3    31        0              31
#> 4    20        1              31
#> 5    20        1              31
#> 6    20        1              31
#> 7    39        0              39
#> 8    28        0              28
```

Comment: This is what I was thinking about in the car after staring at the problem for two hours.

Answer (score 2):

You can turn the `Price` to `NA` where  `Discount = 1` and then use `zoo`'s `na.locf` to fill those values with the previous value.

```
df$PrevailingPrice <- df$Price
df$PrevailingPrice[df$Discount == 1] <- NA
df$PrevailingPrice <- zoo::na.locf(df$PrevailingPrice)
df

#  Price Discount PrevailingPrice
#1   $30        0             $30
#2   $39        0             $39
#3   $31        0             $31
#4   $20        1             $31
#5   $20        1             $31
#6   $20        1             $31
#7   $39        0             $39
#8   $28        0             $28
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Price = c("$30", "$39", "$31", "$20", "$20", "$20", 
"$39", "$28"), Discount = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```